# Running delayed work on Azure Mobile Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, async-await

I'm trying to build a game server on Azure. I have a controller that is supposed to trigger an airstrike in the game, after 30 seconds.

I'm new to C# and Azure. Here is my poor attempt:

```
public class CallAirstrikeController : ApiController
{

    public ApiServices Services { get; set; }

    public Whatever Post(Coordinate coordinate)
    {
        CallAirstrike(coordinate); // Don't wait
        // Do other things...
        return whatever;
    }

    private async Task CallAirstrike(Coordinate coordinate)
    {
        await Task.Delay(30000); // Wait for it...
        CreateExplosion(coordinate); // Boom
    }

}
```

The controller returns immediately as expected, but it doesn't look like `CreateExplosion` is called at any point.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution, here it is:

```
Task.Run( async () => await CallAirstrike(coordinate) );
```